# logging.BasicConfig encoding param is not working

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, python-logging, python-3.11

I'm getting logging error (`UnicodeEncodeError`) while trying log and print url which contain not ASCII letter. I specified encoding while setting up logger in `my_logging.py`

---

`my_logging.py`

```
import logging
import sys
from pathlib import Path


def get_logger(filepath: Path) -> None:
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        encoding='utf-8',
        format="[{asctime},{msecs:03.0f}]:[{levelname}]:{message}",
        datefmt='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S',
        style='{',
        handlers=[
            logging.FileHandler(filepath, mode='a'),
            logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout),
        ]
    )

    logging.getLogger('asyncio').setLevel(logging.WARNING)


def log_and_print(msg: str) -> None:
    logging.info(msg)
    print(msg)
```

Error:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1113, in emit
    stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 156-157: character maps to <undefined>
Call stack:
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\30.rossiya-airlines\app.py", line 162, in run
    asyncio.run(download_reports_for_month(login=self.login, password=self.password, month=self.month))
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 640, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 321, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1922, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\30.rossiya-airlines\scrapper.py", line 138, in download_reports_for_month
    await _download_reports_for_month(login=login, password=password, month=month)
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\30.rossiya-airlines\scrapper.py", line 169, in _download_reports_for_month
    log_and_print(f'Start downloading {url=}')
  File "C:\Users\vboxuser\30.rossiya-airlines\my_logging.py", line 27, in log_and_print
    logging.info(msg)
Message: "Start downloading url='https://edu.rossiya-airlines.com/workplan/view_flight_report-1?flight_date=02-08-2023&flight_number=ФВ6321&legnum=1&departure_airport_id=705&arrival_airport_id=307&id_para=1214928'"
Arguments: ()
```

Line raising error:

```
log_and_print(f'Start downloading {url=}')
```

---

I can workaround exceptions by encoding every msg manually:

```
def log_and_print(msg: str) -> None:
    logging.info(msg.encode('utf-8')
    print(msg)
```

But then binary prefix appears. I don't like it so much and want to understand why passing `encoding='utf-8'` in `logging.BasicConfig` is not working as I expect. What am i missing?

---

`Windows 10`, `Python 3.11.4`

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are experiencing is due to the fact that the `StreamHandler` used to log messages to the console is using the default encoding of your system, which is `cp1252` on Windows. This encoding does not support all `Unicode` characters, which is why you are getting a UnicodeEncodeError when trying to log a message containing `non-ASCII` characters.

The encoding parameter in the `basicConfig` function only applies to the `FileHandler`, which is used to log messages to a file. It does not affect the encoding used by the `StreamHandler`.

To fix this issue, you can explicitly set the encoding of the `StreamHandler` to 'utf-8' when creating it. Please refer below:

```
import logging
import sys
from pathlib import Path

def get_logger(filepath: Path) -> None:
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt="[{asctime},{msecs:03.0f}]:[{levelname}]:{message}", datefmt='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S', style='{'))
    
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format="[{asctime},{msecs:03.0f}]:[{levelname}]:{message}",
        datefmt='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S',
        style='{',
        handlers=[
            logging.FileHandler(filepath, mode='a', encoding='utf-8'),
            stream_handler,
        ]
    )

    logging.getLogger('asyncio').setLevel(logging.WARNING)

def log_and_print(msg: str) -> None:
    logging.info(msg)
    print(msg)
```

In the above code, we create a `StreamHandler` object and set its stream to `sys.stdout` and its `formatter` to a Formatter object with the desired format. We then pass this StreamHandler object to the handlers parameter of the basicConfig function, along with the FileHandler.

Comment: *"you can explicitly set the encoding of the StreamHandler to 'utf-8' when creating it."* Where in this code is the encoding of the StreamHandler explicitly set?

Comment: Passing `encoding` to `FileHandler` helped!

Comment: "_The encoding parameter in the basicConfig function only applies to the FileHandler_" seems like not, because I got error with `logging.basicConfig(encoding='utf-8')`, but not with `logging.basicConfig(handlers=[logging.FileHandler(filepath, mode='a', encoding='utf-8')])`

Comment: I agree with @slothrop. anyway you put me in the correct direction, thanks. May be correct answer a little bit and i will accept it

Comment: I've made the necessary modifications to the `get_logger` function. In the get_logger function, I created a StreamHandler object with a custom formatter and added it to the handlers parameter of the basicConfig function. This allows you to control the format of the messages logged to the console. FileHandler is set with ‘utf-8’ encoding.